# Error objective-c IN APP PURCHASE implementation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing the IN APP PURCHASE and I'm not a very experienced developer.
I'm using the brant troy tutorial I found here:
[Tutorial](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/comment-page-4/#comment-11008)

I have the error in loadStore method implementation:
Sending ‘InAppPurchaseManager *const __strong’ to parameter of incompatible type ‘id’

```
//
//  InAppPurchaseManager.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface InAppPurchaseManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate>
{
    SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
}

// public methods
- (void)loadStore;
- (BOOL)canMakePurchases;
- (void)purchaseProUpgrade;

@end

---

#import "InAppPurchaseManager.h"

#define kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId @"com.user.app.product"

@implementation InAppPurchaseManager

- (void)loadStore
{
    // restarts any purchases if they were interrupted last time the app was open

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver: self];
ERROR HERE: Sending 'InAppPurchaseManager *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<SKPaymentTransactionObserver>'

    // get the product description (defined in early sections)
    [self requestProUpgradeProductData];
}

@end
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is just like kperryua said, but just to make it clear:

```
@interface InAppPurchaseManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate,SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
{
SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
}

// public methods
- (void)loadStore;
- (BOOL)canMakePurchases;
- (void)purchaseProUpgrade;

@end
```

it should work just fine.

Comment: Ooooooh NO. I have made it in the past. Now it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare that `InAppPurchaseManager` conforms to the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` protocol.